# Symfony2 : Share Bundles between 2 projects

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

Our company decided to move to Symfony2 and now we are trying to re-write our application. I'm still new to Symfony2 and trying to figure out what is the best way to build the app.

our app consists of 2 part each part is on a different server:

- **A** contains all the logic required to get/store/update records in database
- **B** users requests go to, process the request and send another request to **A** for any database interaction

I'm planning to use Doctrine in **A** so i created all the required Entities, but i feel i need to share **A** entities with **B** since it's easier to create/validate forms using entities.

- Am I going into the right direction or I don't have to share the entities?
- If I share the entities and **B** doesn't have any database connection, will that create any problem for me?
- If I'm going to do this approach (separate logic and database calls into 2 separate bundles each one on a different server) is there any consequences? where should i build Services ? on **A** or **B** or also i would have to share Services too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the exact problem you described, but I wanted to share/extend some entities between applications in single project. However, I was recommended by good folks on SO to **branch** entire project.

I suppose you will be using Git so you'll have **two branches**: A and B. Both will have common files (entities in you case), but will certainly contain different controllers/services as necessary.

Now, since you've mentioned two servers, not only you will have separated code but you will be able to set different deployment scripts both for A and B.

The downside: I believe that some intermediate knowledge of git branching will be necessary.

Is that acceptable for you?